# User Info needed to SSH using paramiko in python

Tags: python, ssh, ftp, paramiko

I have written the code below:

```
    import os, sys
    import paramiko

    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.connect(server_name, username = ?, password = ?)
```

I'm trying to connect to an ftp server that doesn't need an account (username and password) to get access. However, when I try some of the following:

```
ssh.connect(server_name, username = '', password = '')
```

or

```
ssh.connect(server_name, username = 'anonymous', password = '')
```

or

```
ssh.connect(server_name)
```

I get this error:

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Could someone please explain why I get this error and how to fix it?

Comment: I am guessing this has to do with the `server_name`.

Comment: maybe related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20252294/ssh-could-not-resolve-hostname-hostname-nodename-nor-servname-provided-or-n

Comment: Just curious that connecting to a ftp server over ssh but with anonymous account and no password? That's kinda strange for me, or maybe you are talking about `sftp`?

Answer (score 1):

gai stands for `getaddrinfo()`, which relates to your `server_name`. A common mistake is related to host declaration. If you can give us details about the `server_name` may be helpful.

(Sorry for not answering as a comment, but I'm not able to comment).

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I'm connecting to the ftp site: ftp.ensembl.org/

Comment: I would suggest to change for the IP address 1st, which doesn't need to be resolved. Also, make sure you can connect with anonymous account and no password.