# Mac 10.11 with SVN 1.7.20 : Unable to connect to a repository at URL

Tags: macos, svn

I tried to clone a repository and I got this error.

```
svn: E210002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn+ssh://xxxx@xxxx/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/trunk'
svn: E210002: To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from 'ssh' in the [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file.
svn: E210002: Network connection closed unexpectedly
```

I am using svn version 1.7.20 (r1667490) on Mac 10.11.
I was able clone the same repository from my other PC (Mac 10.6.8) which uses svn version 1.6.17 (r1128011).

I also copied the ~/.ssh folder from the PC that uses svn 1.6.17 to the one with svn 1.7.20 but still get the same error.

Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

On Mac I did this and it worked for me

```
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

I got this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40754476/3365355)

Answer (score 0):

I would check and be sure your permissions are correct on your ssh keys. Copying them over sometimes munges them, and can be a pain to debug. Try `ls -la` in .ssh folder on both computers to be sure the permissions are the same.

Comment: I checked and saw that both have the same permissions.

Comment: Did you try getting more verbose output from ssh by editing your ~/.subversion/config file and adding the parameter like it suggested??

Comment: After editing, it said: ssh: Could not resolve hostname myhost8: nodename nor servname provided, or not known