# git ssh fails to access host but succeed when direct IP is used (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, git, bash, ssh

I am using git/bash in Windows 10 and try to clone a repository.
When I use the command: `git clone username@hostname`, I get:
ssh: Could not resolve hostname stbcmgit: Name or service not known

However, when I use a direct IP address instead of the hostname (`git clone username@x.x.x.x`), the access is successful and the clone starts.

Notes:

- "`known_hosts`" file is located at `c:\Users\myname\.ssh`
  The file is taken from my Linux account where everything works fine there.
- The .ssh folder contains also the `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` keys (copied also from Linux).
- When I use '`ls $HOME/.ssh`', I see these files listed.
- Using Windows 10.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you connecting with hostname, that resolves correctly? Ie. is configured in DNS, or `ssh_config`. Try `nslookup hostname`?

Comment: You can follow the steps in the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20252294/ssh-could-not-resolve-hostname-hostname-nodename-nor-servname-provided-or-n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check `/etc/hosts` and add such a line if it doesn't exist:

```
x.x.x.x hostname
```

---

If the host's IP doesn't change, you can simplify the whole command by creating `$HOME/.ssh/config` like this

```
Host YourHost
    HostName x.x.x.x
    User username
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    PubKeyAuthentication yes
```

Now you can run these commands:

```
git clone YourHost:repo
ssh YourHost
```

Comment: The 2nd suggestion seems to help in this case, Thanks!.

Comment: The 1st suggestion was helpful when using for TortoiseGit.

Answer (score 0):

In **Windows 10** and after the latest updates concerning the "Windows Subsystem for linux" aka ***"Bash"*** now you ***MUST*** assign any desired hostname with its relative IP Address by editing this file:

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

P.S: on your linux please check /etc/hosts and not the 'known_hosts' file

Answer (score 0):

`~/.ssh/config` may contain such definitions.

These definitions contain port numbers also (I think /etc/hosts can't).