# Although CIDER works without projects and the Clojure project is successfully built, why I can't bring both things together?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, cider, nrepl, shadow-cljs

I have a Clojure/ClojureScript project that I am able to build locally. The project is built with the following command:

```bash
Pedros-MacBook-Air:balance pedro$ shadow-cljs watch app

shadow-cljs - config: /Users/pedro/projects/balance/shadow-cljs.edn
NPM dependency "highlight.js" has installed version "^9.16.2"
"11.1.0" was required by jar:file:/Users/pedro/.m2/repository/superstructor/re-highlight/1.1.0/re-highlight-1.1.0.jar!/deps.cljs
shadow-cljs - HTTP server available at http://localhost:3005
shadow-cljs - server version: 2.15.3 running at http://localhost:9630
shadow-cljs - nREPL server started on port 8230
shadow-cljs - watching build :app
[:app] Configuring build.
[:app] Compiling ...
[:app] Build completed. (1155 files, 3 compiled, 4 warnings, 10.88s)
```

Ok. It works!

Also, I am able to use CIDER without a project. After having to answer the question below with `y`:

```
Are you sure you want to run `cider-jack-in' without a Clojure project? (y or n) y
```

I am able to run CIDER and I have REPL powers. Ok.

So, `shadow-cljs` *and* CIDER both wok, but separately. **Now, I want to have both running together!**

However, in the above-mentioned project successfully built, I can't use CIDER `jack-in` nor `cider-connect`.

My first attempt was simply moving with Emacs to the project directory and doing `cider-jack-in` which returns:

[image]

The mini-buffer does **not** allow me to type the `shadow-cljs watch app` command. I **cannot** even introduce whitespaces.

If I just insert the first desired word, `shadow-cljs`, Emacs returns that

> user-error: The npx shadow-cljs executable isn’t on your ‘exec-path’

**I must highlight that the same error message is retrieved** no matter what the specific `cider-jack-in` used. Both `cider-jack-in` and `cider-jack-in-cljs` retrieve the same error message.

I do not how exactly to solve it. Why I can't even type things with freedom?

My second attempt was trying `cider connect`. For the info on `host` and `port`, I used the "build data" provided earlier:

```
shadow-cljs - HTTP server available at http://localhost:3005
shadow-cljs - server version: 2.15.3 running at http://localhost:9630
shadow-cljs - nREPL server started on port 8230
```

First, the mini-buffer asked for `Host:` which I replied with:

```lisp
http://localhost
```

And then for `Port:`, which I replied with:

```lisp
8320
```

I got:

```
nrepl-connect: [nREPL] Direct connection to http://localhost:8230 failed; try setting ‘nrepl-use-ssh-fallback-for-remote-hosts’ to t
```

After that, I tried an eval of the s-expression below via `eval-expression` (bounded to `M :`):

```lisp
(setq nrepl-use-ssh-fallback-for-remote-hosts t)
```

But, it was not enough. Emacs returns:

```
nrepl--ssh-tunnel-connect: [nREPL] SSH port forwarding failed.  Check the ’*nrepl-tunnel projects/balance:localhost*<2>’ buffer
```

If I switch buffer to `*nrepl-tunnel projects/balance:localhost*<2>` this is what I have:

```
OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/pedro/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/pedro/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to http port 22.
ssh: Could not resolve hostname http: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Process nrepl-tunnel exited abnormally with code 255
```

Obs.: I am using macOS 12.5 on a MacBook Air M1. Is [this a possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20252294/ssh-could-not-resolve-hostname-hostname-nodename-nor-servname-provided-or-n) solution?

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to run a ClojureScript project as a Clojure project. You should use [`cider-jack-in-cljs`](https://docs.cider.mx/cider/basics/clojurescript.html#_starting_a_clojurescript_repl) instead. When prompted select `shadow-cljs` as command to be used, `shadow` for ClojureScript REPL type and `app` for shadow-cljs build.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! Unfortunately, it did not work out. I will update my question including your suggestion. Regardless of the use of `cider-jack-in` or `cider-jack-in-cljs`, the same error message is retrieved.

Comment: Does it work if you run `npx shadow-cljs watch app` directly in your terminal? If not, install [`npx`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx) with `npm install -g npx`.

Comment: Ok, thanks again. But, why do I need `npx` for CIDER if I am able to build the project without `npx` on terminal?

Comment: The default `cider-shadow-cljs-command` is `npx shadow-cljs`, see [CIDER > ClojureScript Setup > Using shadow-cljs > Configuration](https://docs.cider.mx/cider/cljs/shadow-cljs.html#configuration). You can set the `cider-shadow-cljs-command` variable to `shadow-cljs` (`M-x set-variable`)  if you do not want to use `npx`. Advantage of using `npx` is that you don't need to have `shadow-cljs` installed globally.

Comment: Thanks. I believe the REPL has started. The advice on setting a variable was a killing one!