# ssh custom host/hostname not working on Mac

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have an ssh configuration file as follows:

```
Host github
   User git
   Hostname github.com
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host github.com-work
   User git
   Hostname github.com
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/work
```

I have access to all the (private) github repos and have added public keys already. But when I tried

`ssh -T git@github.com-work`

It throws this error:

`ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com-work: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`

What could be the reason for this error?

Comment: Where is that ssh configuration located? It seems to work for me as written when placed in `~/.ssh/config`.

Comment: @larsks it is located in ~/.ssh/config

Answer (score 0):

First, the idea behind adding `User git` in your ~/ssh/config file is to *avoid* using `git@` in the SSH URL.

Second, check what config file is actually read with:

```
ssh -Tv github.com-work
```

As you can [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20252294/6309), it can depend on your OS, or the current user executing the `ssh` command.

Comment: Yeah I even tried without git but still the same error.